# initialising a Queue which has a struct

Tags: c, struct, queue

Error - invalid type of argument (the location of the error is in the main function where I initialize the Queue.)
  I declared a struct of Queue which has 2 pointers of another struct(called) Dataitem.

```
    // list dataitem declaration
       struct dataitem{
       Cake cake;
       struct dataitem *next;
        };

       typedef struct dataitem Dataitem;
       typedef Dataitem *DataitemPtr;

      // Queue declaration
      struct queue{
      int countQ;
      Dataitem *headPtr;
      Dataitem * tailPtr;
      };
      typedef struct queue Queue;
```

I am initializing the Queue inside the main function as follows.The error is caught here.Could I please know why this error occurs?

```
      Queue q;
      q->headPtr=q->tailPtr = NULL;
      q.countQ=0;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong syntax. Use `.` instead of `->`.

```
  q.headPtr = q.tailPtr = NULL;
```

To access a member of an object, you need to use `.` operator. The fact that `headPtr` is a pointer does not mean you need to use the `->` operator to access members of `q`. You will need to use the `->` operator to access the members of `q.headPtr`.

```
 q.headPtr->next = NULL;
```

Comment: But headPtr and tailPtr are pointers and C says to initialize pointers with `->`.

Comment: Now I get a runtime error. It doesn't compile.

Comment: It doesn't compile and it doesn't run are two different things.

Comment: the code I made has no error , but the :makefile.win" they show an error. I am using dev C ++ to run my c code.

Comment: Is the error related to the change I suggested? Somewhere else?

Comment: no the error isn't related to the change you suggested. Fixed it thanks a lot but I don't get why the pointers should be initialized by `.` rather than `->`